# java: Declare array from nested class

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java. Let's say I have something like the following:

```
public class OuterClass {
    ...
    ...
    public class InnerClass {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

How would I declare an array of type InnerClass in main, if it is nested in OuterClass.This does not work.

```
InnerClass[] innerClassArray = new InnerClass[size]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between Person and InnerClass and OuterClass?

Comment: Sorry I was working on something else and did that by accident.... I edited my post.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299833/create-array-of-inner-class-object-in-a-different-class

Answer (score 0):

An instance of InnerClass can't exist except as part of an instance of OuterClass and the class definition of InnerClass is tied to the class definition of OuterClass.

More correct would be:

```
Outerclass.InnerClass[] innerClassArray = new Outerclass.InnerClass[size];
```

And to populate it:

```
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
innerClassArray[0] = outer.new InnerClass();
innerClassArray[1] = outer.new InnerClass();
```