# How to make an array from a class defined inside another class

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I am a novice Java programmer trying to use classes defined in a different file. So, I've written these two .java files:

**First, there's MyLibrary.java:**

```
package mymainprogram;

public class MyLibrary {
    public class MyRecord {
        int number;
        char letter;
    }

    public static int TriplePlusThree(int input_number) {            
        return ((input_number*3) + 3);
    }
}
```

**Then, MyMainProgram.java:**

```
package mymainprogram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyread = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Number to Process: ");
        int num = keyread.nextInt();  
        int result = MyLibrary.TriplePlusThree(num);
        System.out.println("3x + 3 = "+result);

        String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        MyLibrary.MyRecord[] TenRecs = new MyLibrary.MyRecord[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TenRecs[i].number = i;      //NullPointerException here
            TenRecs[i].letter = letters.charAt(i);           
        }
    }
}
```

I had no problem getting the method to work just fine; now my goal is to create an array where each member of the array has an integer and character. (Note: I'm not looking for better ways to accomplish this objective; I'm merely using this trivial example to try to get this working).

When I tried to run my program, I got:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I researched this, and found [this page](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects), which says:

> If we try to access the objects even before creating them, run time errors would occur. For instance, the following statement throws a NullPointerException during runtime which indicates that [this array] isn't yet pointing to [an] object. The objects have to be instantiated using the constructor of the class and their references should be assigned to the array elements in the following way.

```
studentArray[0] = new Student();
```

So, I tried to do that in my Main Program:

```
MyRecordArray[0] = new MyLibrary.MyRecord();
```

but that gives this error:

> an enclosing instance that contains MyLibrary.MyRecord is required

That error message led me to [this Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619505/how-can-i-resolve-an-enclosing-instance-that-contains-x-y-is-required), which says:

> you have to create an object of X class (outer class) and then use objX.new InnerClass() syntax to create an object of Y class.

```
X x   = new X();
X.Y y = x.new Y();
```

---

So, in accordance with that answer, I've added these two lines to my program:

```
MyLibrary mylibrary         = new MyLibrary();
MyLibrary.MyRecord myrecord = mylibrary.new MyRecord();
```

Those lines don't give any warnings or compilation errors, so I feel like I'm one step closer, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make an array. I know if I wanted to make an array of integers, I would simply do this:

```
int[] TenInts = new int[10];
```

So, I've tried things like:

```
myrecord[] TenRecs = new myrecord[10];
MyRecord[] TenRecs = new MyRecord[10];
```

But nothing is working, and I feel like I'm grasping at straws now. I get the feeling that the right set of eyes could solve this pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the inner class as static.

You can modify the code as follows to suit your requirements:

This is the code for MyLibrary

```
public class MyLibrary {

    public static class MyRecord{
        int number;
        char letter;

        public MyRecord(){
            number = 0;
            letter = '\0';
        }

        public MyRecord(int number, char letter){
            this.number = number;
            this.letter = letter;
        }
    }

    public static int TriplePlusThree(int input_number){ 
        return (input_number * 3 + 3);
    }
}
```

This is the code for the MyMainProgram

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyMainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number to process");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("3x + 3 = " + MyLibrary.TriplePlusThree(num));

        String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
        MyLibrary.MyRecord[] TenRecords = new MyLibrary.MyRecord[2];

        for (int i=0; i<TenRecords.length; i++){
            TenRecords[i] = new MyLibrary.MyRecord();
            TenRecords[i].number = i;
            TenRecords[i].letter = letters.charAt(i); 
        }

        // Printing class records
        for (int i=0; i<TenRecords.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Printing records of record " + i + " : ");
            System.out.println("Number : " + TenRecords[i].number);
            System.out.println("Letter : " + TenRecords[i].letter);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

You can create the instance of the inner class as follows:

```
TenRecords[i] = new MyLibrary.MyRecord();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The nested class `MyRecord` contains a hidden reference to the outer class `MyLibrary` and therefore must be associated with an instance of `MyLibrary`. This way `MyRecord` can access private members of `MyLibrary`.

```
MyLibrary.MyRecord myrecord = mylibrary.new MyRecord();
```

Wow, this is funny syntax. In all my years of java programming, I never used such a construct. Typically, you would create objects of inner classes (`MyRecord`) within the outer class (`MyLibrary`). Another common thing is to declare the inner class as `static` which would eliminate the need for an instance of the outer class.

---

```
MyRecord[] TenRecs = new MyRecord[10];
```

This will create an array where all the elements are NULL. You have to initialize each of them (e.g. with a loop).

Comment: I'll admit, it's a funny syntax. I was just trying to follow the syntax on that other answer, which had garnered 50 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you need to note.
First, difference between a instance inner class and a static inner class.

An instance inner class, declared without `static` modifier,

```
public class OutterClass {
    public class InstanceInnerClass {}
}
```

should be created like this:

```
OutterClass outter = new OutterClass();
InstanceInnerClass iInner = outter.new InstanceInnerClass();
```

while a static inner class, declared with `static` modifier,

```
public class OutterClass {
    public static class StaticInnerClass {}
}
```

should be created like this:

```
StaticInnerClass sInner = new OutterClass.StaticInnerClass();
```

Secondly, you accessed an array entry before it is filled

```
MyLibrary library = new MyLibrary();
MyLibrary.MyRecord[] TenRecs = new MyLibrary.MyRecord[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Create new instance
    TenRecs[i] = library.new MyRecord();
    TenRecs[i].number = i;
    TenRecs[i].letter = letters.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize `MyRecord[10]` the array has null objects. You still have to initialize each element in the array to a new `MyRecord` object. Otherwise you will get the `NPE`.

one way to do is : `List<MyRecord> TenRecs = new ArrayList<MyRecord>();`
`TenRecs.add( new MyRecord() );`

or `for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) TenRecs[i] = new MyRecord();`

also if you add an import statement : `import mymainpackage.MyLibrary.MyRecord;` You don't need to do `mylibrary.new MyRecord();` just do `new MyRecord();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create each object in array before initialize. Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299833/create-array-of-inner-class-object-in-a-different-class).

Create each object like this.

```
MyLibrary outer = new MyLibrary();
TenRecs[i] = outer.new MyRecord();
```

Full code:

```
MyLibrary.MyRecord[] TenRecs = new MyLibrary.MyRecord[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        MyLibrary outer = new MyLibrary();
        TenRecs[i] = outer.new MyRecord();
        TenRecs[i].number = i; 
        TenRecs[i].letter = letters.charAt(i);  
    }
```