# Array of inner class objects inside a teplated class

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, inner-classes

**Based on what I read here [StackOverFlow array from a class...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045244/how-to-make-an-array-from-a-class-defined-inside-another-class), I expected the following code to compile. I get an error, "<identifier> expected". I get the same result with Array.newInstance. What am I doing wrong?**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
public class Outer<E> {
    private Inner[] array;
    
    public Outer() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        array = (Inner[])new Outer<?>.Inner[10];
        //array = (Inner[])Array.newInstance(Inner.class, 10);
    }
    
    public class Inner {
        E data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
class Outer<E> {
    private Inner[] array;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Outer() {
        array = (Inner[])new Outer<?>.Inner[10];
        //array = (Inner[])Array.newInstance(Inner.class, 10);
    }
    
    
    public class Inner {
        E data;
    }
}
```

Suppress warnings outside of the constructor